# Setting up google oauth for chrome extension. authorized domain

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

When setting up the Google OAuth consent screen for a new project (a chrome extension), what exactly should be put in the `Authorized Domains` field?  If my extension can pop up on any website, then is there any way for me to fill this out so I can log in to the extension?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: There is no code and no errors, I haven't gotten that far as I'm unclear how to set it up in google's portal. 
 As the question says, I need to know how to set it up before I can get that far. 
 https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/consent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase_in_a_chrome_extension

You basically need to introduce `chrome-extension://CHROME_EXTENSION_ID` in the Authorized domains field

Comment: Thanks, this documentation looks new since I asked the question as I don't remember seeing this before (this answer was posted over a year later). What we ended up doing was having a website do all the auth stuff and then just passing along any auth information directly to the extension. This looks like it would work now so I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer.